# Heroku deployment of React Flask app within the same repo

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, heroku, heroku-cli

I was deploying my flask react application to Heroku. It's all located in the same folder. My app.py code is here

```
import time
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='build/', template_folder="build", static_url_path='/')

CORS(app)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def serve(path):
    if path != "" and os.path.exists(app.static_folder + '/' + path):
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, path)
    else:
        return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here's an image of my folder structure:

[image]

I deployed it on Heroku but I find 404 error. The code seems to work fine on localhost though, and I have tried everything I could do. My other APIs which send data seem to work fine. It's just the issue with this one.

Comment: The `build/` directory is ignored by git, so won't be in the code you push to Heroku. Do you have the JavaScript buildpack configured to build the React app *before* the Python buildpack serves the Flask app? See e.g. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app - you should see something like `1. heroku/nodejs 2. heroku/python`.

Comment: Oh, yes! I had not build my react project before the Python build. Your solution works like charm. Thank you so much @jonrsharpe